# What's the right way to install Polymer elements at a specific version?

Tags: polymer, bower

Recently Polymer [updated from 0.5.2 to 0.5.3](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/releases). Some of these changes affect the styling of my components, e.g.:

> **paper-checkbox**
>
> Updated paper-checkbox to match Material Design guidelines
>
> To style properly, must now set `border-color` along with `background-color`

My bower include targets a specific version:

```
"paper-elements": "Polymer/paper-elements#0.5.2"
```

but `bower.json` in paper-elements uses the carat:

```
"paper-checkbox": "Polymer/paper-checkbox#^0.5.0"
```

so when I run `bower update` it happily fetches paper-checkbox version 0.5.4.

Is there a way to ensure bower grabs a specific version of these dependencies, without having to list every single package in my own `bower.json`? E.g., I could explicitly specify paper-checkbox#0.5.2, but because paper-checkbox has its own dependencies using the carat syntax, I'd have to include all dependencies of all the elements I use recursively.

Am I just supposed to immediately update my code whenever a new Polymer minor version is released?

Comment: Have you tried using `bower install` instead of update?

Comment: @Cristian Yes, no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer is yes, I do need to explicitly list all dependencies in the entire dependency graph if I want to ensure bower pulls down exact versions of those packages. Oh well!